# Changing a JSONB keys to uppercase

Tags: sql, postgresql, jsonb

I have a table with many fields, but the only important one here is `meta` which is a JSONB field (there is also a primary key, `id`, if needed). In this field, there is always a dict with key => value data, like this :

```
{
  "card": "gold",
  "country": "France",
  "Type of travel": "Business",
  "Company": "KLM"
}
```

I need to update this field to put every key in uppercase, like this :

```
{
  "CARD": "gold",
  "COUNTRY": "France",
  "TYPE OF TRAVEL": "Business",
  "COMPANY": "KLM"
}
```

The values, however, must keep their current cases - only the key are to be impacted.

I wrote a python script to do that, however it took multiple hours to update my testing set of 600k rows. The problem is that my production set is actually 2.5M rows and as long as the script is running I must stop the production, so I can't really have it running for days...

Is there any way to do this update in a full-sql way ? And would that be faster ?

I should add that there is no known list of possible keys in the field - the exact keys may (and do) vary from one rows to another, so I can't just say "here are the new keys", I need to retrieve them from them json object first.

Edit: The python script I tried to use is a Django management comment, so it use the ORM, but here it is :

```py
print("Step 2: Verbatim...\t\t\tCounting...", end='\r')
verbatims = Verbatim.objects.all()
i = 0
total = len(verbatims)
to_save = []
for verbatim in verbatims:
  verbatim.meta = up_dict(verbatim.meta)
  to_save.append(verbatim)
  i += 1
  if i % 100 == 1:
    print(f"Step 2: Verbatim...\t\t\t{i}/{total}", end='\r')
  print("Step 2: Verbatim...\t\t\tSaving...               ", end='\r')
  Verbatim.objects.bulk_update(to_save, ['meta'], batch_size=10000)
  print("Step 2: Verbatim...\t\t\t[OK]                    ")
```

It take around 5 secondes to go start the "counting" part, then around 2 seconds for the whole loop. Then the "saving" part was killed by the DB after 2 hours. Oh, and here is the `up_dict` function, if needed:

```py
def up_dict(original):
    return {
        key.upper(): original[key] for key in original
    }
```

Comment: *"I wrote a python script to do that"* - Show it, please.

Comment: @Tomalak updated the post to add the script

Comment: No, the entire thing. The DB connection, the DB query, the loop that updates data,  and the part that writes data back to the DB.

Comment: Well, that's the entire thing :x It's a django script so I'm not creating the DB connection nor writing the DB query, it's using the ORM for me. The loop that update the data is the one I posted, and the part that write it back to the DB is the second-to-last line

Answer (score 2):

Extract all elements with `jsonb_each_text`, use `upper` to change the keys and aggregate them again with `jsonb_object_agg`:

```
SELECT 
  jsonb_object_agg(upper(key),value)
FROM jsonb_each_text(
'{
  "card": "gold",
  "country": "France",
  "Type of travel": "Business",
  "Company": "KLM"
}'::jsonb);

                                   jsonb_object_agg                                    
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 {"CARD": "gold", "COMPANY": "KLM", "COUNTRY": "France", "TYPE OF TRAVEL": "Business"}
(1 row)
```

Assuming that the jsonb document has an `id` of some sort, you can update your table like this:

```
WITH j (id,doc_upper) AS (
  SELECT id,jsonb_object_agg(upper(k),v) FROM t
  CROSS JOIN LATERAL jsonb_each_text(doc) j(k,v)
  GROUP BY id
)
UPDATE t SET doc = j.doc_upper
FROM j WHERE j.id = t.id;
```

Demo: [`db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=6e96fa6b6cca63cde8c5ebbb638b2704)

Comment: Thank you for the hint ! However I'm not sure how I could use it to update the rows inplace... Can I use this as a subquery in an update ?

Comment: @YannPIQUET does the table have a primary key or a unique constraint?

Comment: there is a primary key named `id`

Comment: @YannPIQUET did you check my last edit? Take a look at the second query and fiddle

Comment: Sorry, I started typing and ended up forgetting to send the reply... I did checked it and tryed it on our dev env, but it still took multiple hours :/ In the end I created a script using a threaded algorithm that took an hour and a half, that was the best solution I found

Comment: @YannPIQUET that's odd.. it should work (tested in the fiddle). Which error message you got? Anyways, the important thing is that you solved your problem :) cheers +1 for reporting.

Comment: Sorry, I may have phrased it wrong : it did indeed work, the only problem was that it took too long to run - we have multiple hundred thousands rows in the dev env and multiple millions in the production env. Speed was a huge problem for us, because as long as it was running we had to close the platform (those things are used to set some view rights for users)